# What are metaphorical sayings similar to “As Above So Below”? How can I find them?

Tags: analogy

I am looking for some metaphorical sayings which contain idealist(in contrast to materialism) background like "As Above So Below", and how to find them. Any help is appreciated.
Explanation of this saying can be found in the books that tells about Hermes, an Olympian god in Greek mythology.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Philosophy.SE. Please consider taking the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) and checking our [help center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). This question appears to be a bad fit for this site, since we are looking for limited questions with definite answers. This seems to be both open-ended and depending on opinion, since it is unclear what 'deep sayings' are supposed to be or what this has to do with philosophy as such (ie. an academic practice or at least systematic quest for knowledge).

Comment: Deep means containing metaphor + philosophical ideology(here it is idealism.) I edited it to make it clearer.

Comment: As you can see I have already asked that. It is not shocking that someone is impressed by a saying and go out there ask for other books or any sources that can lead to more.

Comment: So you are specifically looking for *sayings*, not philosophical ideas similar to "As above, so below"?

Comment: Something should first be an idea before it is a saying. Your answer was helpful why delete? Those "ideas", which you split from "saying" could lead me to read about them, and discover more. I am a physics engineer. Not many people around me to get advice about philosophy.

Comment: Maybe you would be interested in this. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giordano_Bruno_and_the_Hermetic_Tradition I agree that Hypnosifl gave a good answer. I think you are in good faith, but it is difficult for us to understand your question.

Comment: Noetic Society https://archive.org/details/20170804NSFRI ; https://archive.org/details/%40noetic_society?&sort=-publicdate&page=2

Comment: Thank you. Help is appreciated a lot.

Comment: I deleted since I thought maybe I misunderstood what you were asking for, but since you found it helpful I've un-deleted it.

Comment: You may also be interested in the more contemporary work of this man, Pierre Hadot:  https://www.iep.utm.edu/hadot/

Comment: Makes me think of ["And As It Is Such, So Also As Such Is It Unto You"](https://arresteddevelopment.fandom.com/wiki/And_As_It_Is_Such,_So_Also_As_Such_Is_It_Unto_You).

Comment: If *As above so below* calls you so may [All is One](https://archive.ashrama.org/docs/all-io/)

Answer (score 3):

This phrase is also found in discussions of Gnosticism. Gnosticism became extinct. *The Nag Hammadi Library* dates back to the 4th century (CE) and it is currently in print.  A text you might be interested in reading comes from 
The book of Thomas.  The passage numbered 25 reads:

> When you make the two one, and when you make the inside like the
>   outside and the outside like the inside, and **the above like the below**,
>   and when you make the male and the female one and the same, so that
>   the male not be the male nor the female female, and when you fashion
>   eyes in place of an eye, and a hand in place of a hand, and a foot in
>   place of a foot, and a likeness in place of a likeness; then you will
>   enter...

Answer (score 2):

"As above, so below" is a phrase from [Hermeticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermeticism), which is more of an occult tradition than a philosophical one (though it has certain similarities to [Neoplatonism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/neoplatonism/), perhaps because both emerged around the same time and place and so drew from a similar set of ideas and intellectual/religious trends...also note that the term Hermeticism refers to the mythical figure of [Hermes trismegistus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermes_Trismegistus) who was not necessarily thought to be the same as the greek god Hermes). But for an analogous idea that has appeared in more philosophical contexts you might look into the notion of each individual human as a ["microcosm"](https://www.britannica.com/topic/microcosm) whose nature parallels that of the whole cosmos in certain ways. There is also Plato's idea that just as each person has an individual soul, the cosmos as a whole has one too, the "world soul" or [Anima mundi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anima_mundi) (there's a book on the subject [here](https://books.google.com/books/about/World_Soul_Anima_Mundi.html?id=VCXGDwAAQBAJ)).